# Do the US and most EU countries effectively have a flat income tax system?

Tags: economy, taxes

In the US and most EU countries, there is a progressive income tax system. However, income tax is not the only tax and there many other direct and indirect taxes. Almost all other taxes, such as consumption/VAT/sales taxes and payroll taxes, are considered regressive taxes that affect lower-earners more. If these taxes are all added together then the tax system is actually not as progressive as people think. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXCGbAv8YPw) they show that the total tax is almost a flat tax.

I have always read that proposals to replace all taxes with a single flat income tax are considered regressive. But, doesn't it seem that we already live under a flat income tax system?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if we're living under a flat income tax system, or are you telling us we're living under a flat income tax system and putting a question mark at the end of it?

Comment: @JoeC, I am asking if it is true that we effectively live under flat tax system. And if it true then why don't we replace all taxes with a flat tax system. Surely the tax code would be much simpler that way.

Comment: In Europe, VAT typically isn't a flat tax either. It's a two/three tier system (depending on whether you include the 0% rate). The apparent subject of the question is **income tax** though, not sales taxes.

Comment: @MSalters No, it's about the combined effect of various taxes relative to a person's income, no matter whether they are ostensibly tied to income or not. From that perspective, VAT is mostly flat, different rates only matter inasmuch as people with different incomes tend to have a different mix of goods falling in each of the VAT categories.

Comment: Who are "we?" Some people who read this question may be subject to different tax codes from some other people.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, I was mainly referring to the US. However, most other countries also tend to use a combination of a progressive income tax and a set of different regressive tax.

Comment: @gbd Even within the US there are large variances between states and, within states, between municipalities. Texas has higher property taxes than Alabama, but there are no taxes on groceries in Texas, whereas in Alabama there is a 4% tax (State) on groceries and municipalities often add on their own as well.  In Birmingham, I pay about 8.5% tax (total state+local) on groceries, but my property taxes are lower on the house I have here than they were on the house I owned in Texas, even though my house here cost more than twice as much

Comment: @SolomonSlow:Good point.  I submitted an edit to clarify the title.

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable.  The problem is that the supposed "flat" taxes - sales tax, VAT, property tax, &c - are mostly consumption taxes, and so the amount any individual pays depends on their behavior.  For instance, many US states have state lotteries, taxes on (legal) gambling, hotel room taxes, &c.  I don't gamble or stay in hotels, so I don't pay any of that.

Answer (score 7):

This video, and the analysis from Emmanuel Saez and Gabriel Zucman which it is based on, is the subject of great debate. The best presentation of the arguments against their interpretation of the data, in my opinion, is given in [this article](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2019/11/4/20938229/zucman-saez-tax-rates-top-400) by Matthew Yglesias. The whole thing is worth a read, but I'll just pick out one section in particular to reproduce here:

> ### The headline fact rests on a bunch of assumptions
>
> Treatment of the corporate income tax is particularly important for
> this exercise because Congress enacted a big corporate tax cut in
> 2017.
>
> Prior to that, the Saez/Zucman data shows the top 400 taxpayers paying
> a lower overall tax rate than the top 0.01 percent or the top 0.1
> percent, but a similar rate to the rest of the top 20 percent of the
> income distribution and a clearly higher rate than the bottom 80
> percent.
>
> And this is important because, as first noted by libertarian economic
> historian Phil Magness, changing how corporate income taxes are
> handled makes a big difference in terms of assessing what rate the
> richest Americans are paying in taxes.
>
> The solid orange line represents the tax rates estimated by Saez,
> Zucman, and Piketty’s scholarly article, using the assumption that the
> burden of the corporate income tax is spread across all non-housing
> capital (including small businesses and such), whereas the dotted line
> shows the Saez/Zucman book’s estimates based on the idea that
> corporate taxes are all paid by corporate shareholders.
>
> [image]
>
> Since ownership of corporations is very highly concentrated among the
> richest people, if you consider a corporate tax rate cut to be a pure
> tax cut for owners of tax-paying corporations, then you will get the
> conclusion that the Trump tax cut was an incredible windfall for the
> top 400 taxpayers.
>
> On the right, it’s popular to argue the exact opposite of this: that
> the economic burden of the corporate income tax falls largely on
> workers and that Trump’s tax changes are a boon to wage growth. There
> are well-qualified people with a whole range of views about this,
> though as Saez and Zucman argue in their book, it does seem telling
> that rich people tend to lobby loudly for corporate income tax cuts
> and labor unions do not (if corporate tax cuts really do help workers,
> unions should be the biggest champions for corporate tax cuts).
>
> In any case, the shocking new fact presented in Leonhardt’s column —
> that the very richest people pay a lower tax rate than the middle
> class — is not just a result of policy changes but a result of changes
> in how Saez and Zucman think we should understand the corporate income
> tax, changes from their own work just a year prior.
>
> Beyond those modeling issues, the income estimate for the top 400
> taxpayers is not a direct measurement; the tax data necessary to
> estimate their income after Trump’s tax cuts is not yet available from
> the IRS. Instead, Saez and Zucman write in a technical appendix that
> it “is based on triangulating publicly available sources and it could
> be refined in future work” and they offer various hopes that more
> precise estimation will be possible in the future.
>
> To pile together several controversial assumptions, pair them with an
> uncertain estimate relating to the wealthiest people, compile that
> into a striking new fact that becomes the centerpiece of a media
> rollout aimed simultaneously at promoting a popular book and
> intervening in a presidential primary campaign — all this rubs
> academic instincts the wrong way and helps explain a fair amount of
> the scholarly backlash to Saez and Zucman.

The article also shows that the many different ways of producing these figures lead to very different conclusions: they cite [this work](http://davidsplinter.com/AutenSplinter-Tax_Data_and_Inequality.pdf) by Gerald Auten of the Treasury Department and David Splinter of Congress’s Joint Committee on Taxation:

[image]

In conclusion, then, the figures & estimates presented in the video are based on significant assumptions on where the burden of payroll, sales, corporate, & even estate taxes fall, as well as a simplified view of the situation which ignores secondary economic factors, for example, the effect of increasing capital taxes. Given the disputed state of the available evidence, I don't believe currently there is sufficient evidence to confidently state whether or not we are not living under a flat income tax system.

Comment: (+1) Very useful answer but I am not convinced the quote, data, and reasoning you offer fully support your conclusion. The figures and estimates in the video are certainly based on significant assumptions but if that's the case, other figures are too (if nothing else they are based on the notion that Saez et. al. assumptions do not hold). The fact that some conclusion is based on (disputed) assumptions does not entail that the opposite is true. At most, it means the conclusion is not sufficiently supported.

Comment: Consequently, it would seem to make more sense to write that whether we are living under a flat income tax system depends on how well the assumtions hold/whether you share them.

Comment: @Relaxed I agree, perhaps I wasn't clear enough - by 'in this sense' I meant 'if the assumptions made by the article are incorrect'.

Comment: Also, these data caught the attention of the public when discussing the Trump tax cuts but there are really two different issues here: second-hand effects of a tax *increase/decrease* are neither here nor there when trying to statistically describe the tax burden as a function of income.

Comment: @CDJB, Thank you for this useful answer. But whether the assumptions made are wrong or not, doesn't the fact the almost all taxes (excluding the income tax) tend to be regressive in nature and so once you add it all together the total tax is not as progressive as some tend to think?

Comment: @gbd That really depends on which people you're talking about when you say 'some tend to think', as well as which economist you ask. If we look at the last two graphs above, the red line (Auten-Splinter) shows a relatively progressive overall tax burden, while under Saez-Zucman, it appears fairly flat.

Comment: @CDJB, I maybe misreading the graphs, but the red line (Auten-Splinter) seem to show that the P0-50 income group pay about 12% in taxes while the Top 1% income group pay 50% in taxes. I just find it hard to believe that.

Comment: @gbd the paper from which this analysis is derived is [here](http://davidsplinter.com/AutenSplinter-Tax_Data_and_Inequality.pdf) - it's pretty pithy, but the conclusions pg.28-29, as well as the tables and graphs in the appendix are fairly easily digestible. As I say, this is by no means a solved issue; opinions of economists vary broadly, and there is a reason economics is often regarded as both an art and a science!

Comment: To what geographic area do these figures and diagrams relate to ? USA ? OECD ? World ?

Comment: @Evargalo the same as the article/video in the question which it critiques - the USA.

Comment: I wonder at what to me seems an obvious logical flaw in the analysis: the idea that corporate taxes are all paid by corporate shareholders.  Surely the taxes are ultimately paid by the consumers who purchase a corporation's products, since the taxes are a cost, and the price of goods sold must (in the long term) cover the corporations costs, or it goes bankrupt.